# Webpage that automatically refresh and show the list of files, when someone upload something

Tags: php, file, upload, html

Basically I have my index.php with an upload script.
When someone upload something, the file goes into downloads/, which is a folder without an index so when you reach mysite.xx/downloads/ the page automatically shows all the files. Is there a way to create a custom page that automatically refresh itself when the list of files changes?

Comment: You could try using Ajax request to periodically check if any new files have been added.

Comment: not without something like websockets. Or you check every minute if there is a new file via ajax in a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: You could just refresh the page every 30-60 seconds with JavaScript.

Comment: k I'll try. Thanks